# How can I update HTTP_HOST in Apache for Mautic Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mautic

I install Mautic using docker compose. Then I use NGINX with new domain to point to Mautic. When I run mautic and look at the system information on Admin site, I see the HTTP_HOST pointing to internal IP with port 8080.
How can I change it to domain name?
Many thanks

Comment: Hi @hoang, is you mautic instance is running in port 8080 ?

Comment: Yes, on port 8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the Mautic URL. Please follow below steps.
**Steps**

> => First take backup of your code and move the code to new Hosting
>   folder (Where your new URL pointing to location).
>   => Now change the configuration, go to `app/config/local.php` and change the site url and the file location.
>   => Now clear the cache (`php app/console cache:clear`) and give the file permission.

Now your site is ready.
I hope this will help.

Comment: Actually I think my Mautic version had a problem when changing the Site url. I used another version provided by AWS Marketplace and I I can change it on Admin site. Anyway, thanks for your answer